# ASP.NET MVC & CRM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-dynamics

I am looking for a little guidance for a test project. Previously  I have read that the now discontinued Adxstudio Portals would allow a non AD user to login to CRM using their details in the contacts entity. I am trying to find out if this can be done using ASP.NET.

I am using an on premises version of 365 with IFD. Any assistance or information would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to create an ASP.NET MVC (Core?) site, which uses some form of authentication provider that uses Dynamics 365 as back-end?

Comment: Yes. This is for a test project. I'm trying to explore using ASP.net application for our customers (non AD), to login and view / edit information from CRM. The customers would have a record in the CRM contacts entity.